# Select group of consecutive dates from random datetime pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a pandas datetime column where dates are not sorted. I want to select all the dates for which the next 6 consecutive dates are available in the column without any missing day in between.

My data looks something like this and I have marked the date I want in the image.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a piece of sample data in *text format* to make helping you as easy as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df  = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Sovrflw_data.xlsx')
df
```

## 1 - Sort the dates

```
df.sort_values(by='dates', inplace=True)
```

## 2- run the code to select the dates

```
df[df['dates'] - df['dates'].shift(-6) == timedelta(-6)]
```

## 3 -  If needed undo the sort so the dataframe goes back to the original state

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I think your solution is only valid when the dates are sorted. In my case dates aren't sorted.